# Атрибут __next__ не переопределяется

Tags: python, python-3.x, генераторы, динамическая-типизация

У меня есть класс в котором я переопределяю метод __next __ после его первого вызова, но проблема в том что работать продолжает старый __next __.

```
class I:
    def __init__(self, head):
        self.head = iter(head)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.__next__ = self.head.__next__
        return 'a'


i = I((1, 2, 3))
i_it = iter(i)
print(next(i_it)) #выводит 'a'. Все ок
print(next(i_it)) #снова 'a'. Почему не 1?
print(i_it.__next__) #<method-wrapper '__next__' of tuple_iterator object at 0x7f10d1c03908> вроде __next__ переопределен
```

P.S Если переопределять что-то другое то все работает:

```
    def __next__(self):
        self.__next__ = self.head.__next__
        self.x = 1
        return 'a'
```

После вызова next(self) x будет 1.
Ссылка на онлайн компилятор: https://repl.it/HVOC/17

P.P.S: В коментариях говорят что если вызывать i_it.__next __() то все будет работать так как надо, я это знаю, но штука в том что в любом итераторе(цикл for например) работает next(self), а не self.__next __().

Comment: Возможно, потому что питон на самом деле вызывает не `i_it.__next__()`, а `I.__next__(i_it)`, но точно не уверен

Comment: На самом деле, если вместо next(i_it) вызывать i_it.__next__(), то будет работать всё так, как задумывалось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На сколько я понимаю, в `cpython` встроенная функция `next()` определяется [тут](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e6bb4484ee1b0da67d1dfcf0816c58602daa5a0/Python/bltinmodule.c): `builtin_next()`. Можно увидеть, что при 
[вызове](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e6bb4484ee1b0da67d1dfcf0816c58602daa5a0/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1324) имеется следующая конструкция:

```
res = (*it->ob_type->tp_iternext)(it);
```

Полагаю, что она равносильна примерно такой конструкции на Python:

```
next(i) --> i.__class__.__next__(i)
```

что сходится с тем, что видно на практике.

*Как дела происходят в других интерпретаторах мне не известно.*

Comment: А можно это дело как-то исправить?

Comment: Можно переопределить поведение `next` на то, которое нужно нам. Дописав в начале что-то такое: `next = lambda x : x.__next__()`

Answer (score 0):

Сначала `i_it.__next__ = i.__next__`.

Затем `i.__next__ = self.head.__next__`

Но `i_it.__next__` остался прежним, тк его не меняли.

Те `__next__` был изменен только для объекта класса `i`, но не для итератора `i_it`

Comment: `i` и `i_it` в сущности указывают на один объект. Несложно проверить: `print(i, i_it)`

Comment: Ну да, я ж возвращаю self в iter

Comment: можно легко убедится что после первого next в `i` лежит новый `__next__` и он возвращает цифры, а в `i_it` старый

Comment: Я добавил в онлайн копилятор проверку различия __next __. Посмотрите на вывод строки print(i_it.__next __ is i.__next __)